# How to define an array of strings in C++ and Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi

I need to define an array of string(totally 20), each string contains 255 chars.

In C++, should I use:

```
TCHAR lpArray[255][20];
```

or

```
TCHAR lpArray[20][255];
```

And in Delphi, should I define:

```
lpArray: array[0..254][0..19] of Char;
```

or

```
lpArray: array[0..19][0..254] of Char;
```

Thanks

Comment: If you're interacting with the Windows API, you should be using wide strings, period. No need to support narrow strings in C++ and no need to force narrow strings in Delphi.

Comment: To define array with 20 strings, number of strings should be the left index in both languages, so the second lines are correct. Are you going to perform interaction between programs written with both languages?

Comment: How best to do this depends very much on what you do with the data

Comment: As others have said, how you do this depends on how you use the data. If the two representations must be binary compatible (i.e. if you must exchange between C++ and Delphi), then your approach looks almost fine, but you can also use WideStrings. If binary compatibility is not required, you can simply declare an array of string in Delphi and an array of, say, std::string in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want 20 strings of 255 chars each, so the second set of examples is correct:

```
TCHAR lpArray[20][255];
lpArray: array[0..19][0..254] of Char;
```

The other set of examples create 255 strings of 20 chars each.